# Liquibase + Hibernate ORM 5.0

Tags: hibernate, liquibase, hibernate-5.x, liquibase-hibernate

I'm about to migrate to Hibernate ORM 5.0 and I would like to use Liquibase in my project too.

The [Liquibase Hibernate Extension](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate) mentions `liquibase-hibernate4` for Hibernate 4.3+ support.

**Is there anyone using Liquibase and Hibernate ORM 5.0?**

I want to make sure that there are no issues in Liquibase with the new Hibernate version.

Comment: Did you get an answer to you question? if so, can you please share any findings?

Comment: I had a [performance issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10065) with Hibernate ORM 5.0. So, for now I'm using 4.3.11. It should be fixed in the current release 5.0.1. I didn't test it yet.

Comment: Thanks @IvanRF for the update!

Comment: @TaoufikMohdit I posted the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: on 24-Oct-2016 @nvoxland released [liquibase-hibernate5](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22liquibase-hibernate5%22) 3.6.

Here is the *closed* issue at GitHub: [Issue #96](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues/96).

---

I can finally say that the current [Liquibase Hibernate Extension](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate) (`liquibase-hibernate4`) **is not compatible with Hibernate ORM 5.0.1**.

Here is the error report: [AbstractMethodError in SessionFactoryImpl](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10100)

Steve Ebersole said:

> That line is attempting to call Integrators. I would assume you have Integrators not intended for use with Hibernate 5.0. That contract did change in 5.0 as discussed in the migration guide.